# Running test after a failed build with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, junit

I am using Eclipse Mars for Java. Yesterday I had cause to run a subset of my JUnit tests even though other `.java` files failed to build. There was a dialog to let me do this, unfortunately I cannot remember the exact text but it was something like "There were compile issues. Do you want to run the tests anyway?". Yesterday I checked the "Do not ask me again" box on that dialog. Now I have no idea how to get it back.

How do I undo that preference setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this warning dialog?

[image]

You need to set to **Prompt** to show a warning dialog when you project has compilation error if you decide to test.

Goto:

```
Eclipse - Windows - Preferences - Run/Debug - Lauching

Continue launch if project contains errors
Prompt
```

[image]